# Interfacing html, javascript, php and mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

Below is an order form that I have been working on to learn how html, javascript, php and mysql interact with each other.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7zpok07w1bygu60/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-12%20at%2010.28.41%20AM.png

The goal of this table is to have the user input a number in the quantity field and on the change, javascript will automatically update the total cost of that particular product.  The kicker is that I want the list to be populated from a mysql database table.

Here is the html, javascript and php code that I am using.

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        Product
    </td>
    <td>
        Description
    </td>
    <td>
        Quantity
    </td>
    <td>
        Price
    </td>
    <td>
        Total Cost
    </td>
</tr>

<?php include("pop_prodlist.php"); ?>
<tr>
    <td>Totals</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>TotalQuantity</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>TotalCost</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

PHP

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['P_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['P_Description'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>
    <input type='text' size='3' name='" . $row['P_Name'] . "_Quantity'
      onChange='calcCost()'/>
    </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['P_Cost'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td id='" . $row['P_Name'] . "_Cost'>0.00</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

Javascript calcCost() function

```
    function calcCost()
    {

      var theForm = document.forms['productform'];

    /*
    COMMENTED OUT FOR TIME BEING
    var pquan = theForm.elements[productname + '_Quantity'].value;
    var costperquan = '15.99';
    var ptotalcost = costperquan * pquan;
    */

     var divobj = document.getElementById('Basketball_Cost');
     divobj.innerHTML = "helloworld";

    }
```

The issue that I am currently having is that I cannot figure out how to place an unique argument into the javascript function calcCost from the php script echo depending on the product name decided from the mysql query.

Also, for the sake of educating myself, I am curious as to what a better solution would be/look like.  I doubt that this is the most elegant solution to the problem and I would like to see some better solutions.

Comment: Some things: 1) unless you are printing HTML code, you should escape dynamic output using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars). 2) The ancient mysql_* functions are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @DCoder: very nice, actually wanted to mention that too, so good that you did! :)

Answer (score 3):

Jay, it seems like you understand how PHP, MySQL and JavaScript work together - that is good.

Personally, I can really reccommend using jQuery (JavaScript Library). It is widely used all over the web, very common, powerful and easy to understand and use. Although there are people that say it is not good to use a library of a language, before you know the language, jQuery helped me to understand JavaScript better because of its easy to follow syntax.

So, to use jQuery, you just need to add the source scripts in your html file. Why do I recommend jQuery? It will also allow you to use ajax (loading content, also from the database, without having the page to refresh) very easily.

jQuery will also allow you to separate your click events from your HTML. Basically you assign an `id` or `class` attribute to the HTML elements and this is your reference in your js, so no `onclick=""` required.

As for your HTML: it is highly recommended to not use table-layouts. In a time of HTML5 and CSS3 there are excellent replacements for tables.

If you need more help let me know in the comment, I'm glad to help...

Comment: +1, but tables are fine for tabular data (a shopping cart/order form item list definitely is tabular data).

Comment: @DCoder: oh, if you say so :) but in your opinion, what is the advantage of a table? Or is there anything a table can do that divs or HTML5 elements could not do?

Comment: Semantically, tables should be used for rendering data in a grid/describing a number of objects with the same properties. Which is exactly what we are seeing here.

Comment: if I used divs/elements for this problem would the while loop in my php script above be a lot smaller or is it common to have the php script write a lot of your html with javascript calls?

Comment: @JayBeversdorf: well, the argument of DCoder is understandable. Personally I don't use tables at all, but this is not the point. However, javascript should be seperate from your HTML code. And php should not print your JavaScript code, but you should put your JavaScript in external .js files and include them. In that way the browser can cache them if you use them on multiple sites. Furthermore it improves readability and therefore lowers sources of errors.